# keyframe slide on timeline

Tags: keyframes

I can move keyframe for transform action but how to do it for other animation keyframes like curve bevel start or end ??

here's my code:

```
for o in bpy.context.selected_objects :
    action = o.animation_data.action    
    for i in action.fcurves:
        for keyframe in i.keyframe_points:
            keyframe.co[0]=keyframe.co[0]+10
        i.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `fcurves.find`...you need to access it from `object.data.animation_data` instead of `object.animation_data` (since bevel start end are part of data block). You can find the data path by right clicking on the property in the edit properties panel.

````
for o in bpy.context.selected_objects :
    action = o.data.animation_data.action # Note: o.data.animation_data
    fcurve = action.fcurves.find('bevel_factor_start'):
    for keyframe in fcurve.keyframe_points:
        keyframe.co[0]=keyframe.co[0]+10

```
````

Comment: Thanks Drawer! What if I want both to be updated? I mean o.data.animation AND o.animation.data if exist... I can't figure out how to filter each case

Comment: There are some properties belonging to object and some to object.data. Transform and location are of object and bevel start etc. are in object.data. Not clear what exactly you want to do.